# Building function call through a loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to build search functionality for a reality website.  I want to be able to search by multiple parameters at a time, similar to what you would see on almost any retail website.  I'm using Laravel on my project and I want to be able to make use of the Query Builder so I can use it's built in pagination.

If I try something like:

```
$listing = DB::select('select * from listings where city = 'Chicago');
```

I can't paginate the results.

The other approach would be to do this:

```
$listing = DB::table('listings')->where('city', 'Chicago')->get();
```

But the problem is that I don't know how many parameters a user might enter into the search.  So how would I build a function call that could look like:

```
$listing = DB::table('listings')->where('city', 'Chicago')->where('askingPrice', '>', 50000)->where('bedrooms', '>', 3)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have this parameters:

```
<?php
$parameters = array(
    'one' => 'a',
    'two' => 'b',
    'three' => 'c'
);
```

Create object:

```
<?php
$listing = DB::table('listings');
```

And then, loop:

```
<?php
foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
    $listing = $listing->where($key, $value);
}
```

Of course you have to improve it to handle `>` and others. But I think you get it, right?

At last:

```
<?php
$listing = $listing->get();
```

Comment: Does this query the database multiple times or only when you use get()?

Comment: Only when `get()` is used. `where()` returns `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` not executing query.

Comment: When I do this I can't paginate.  I thought I would be able to substitute `$listing->get();` with `$listing->paginate(20);`

Comment: Not sure what I had done before but I am getting my pagination links now.